# Adding a modification to an EXE in DOS(box)?

Tags: ms-dos, dosbox

I am trying to make an EXE addition work in Dosbox, and with that I mean the following;
 I used to run an old game in XP, it worked (mostly) but now in Win 8 it doesnt anymore. So I fired up Dosbox and it works fine.
 However, I had this modified EXE in windows where I changed to the properties to add 'fastmouse' to the exe. This would make the mouse ingame work faster.

Now, I dont know how to do that in DOS(box), is there a way to type the command, like after typing the exe or so?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: If you need more help than Anksunaman's answer, then please provide us more details.  Exactly how do you successfully start the program?  (What icon do you use, and what do you type?)  If you use an icon, look at the properties of that icon and let us know what executable it runs, and what parameters it uses.  With those details, we can provide more specific instructions regarding what needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Hello, I cant succesful launch the program in Windows anymore.  It is a game, and it always had a shortcut on the desktop.  It was just a shortcut to the exe in the gamefolder. By adding "FASTMOUSE" to the shortcut properties, it would make the mouse work faster.

Since this was in XP , I cant check parameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

DOSBox is an fairly complete emulation of DOS, including the ability to add text parameters to an executable (if supported by that executable).

Assuming you put the modified .exe in the game folder where it would normally go in XP, and assuming you could type something like "game.exe -fastmouse" to start the game while in DOSBox, this should likely work. It certainly does for original DOS executables with text parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried the -FASTMOUSE addition but to no avail. I guess it was a windows command or so. So it wasnt a modified exe (I said it wrong I guess) it was just the original exe, but that fastmouse addition in the shortcut properties triggered faster mous emovement ingame.

Comment: Ah well. So sorry to hear that. Yeah DOSBox is nice, but not perfect in this case I guess. =/